# PC to PC commnication using USB transfer cable, easy cable, USB to USB Bridge cable

Tags: c#, c++, usb

I have a USB transfer cable([easy cable or USB to USB Bridge cable](http://www.alibaba.com/product-tp/146613546/Belkin_Components_BLKF5U279_Easy_Transfer_Cable.html)), it comes with a tool software that can achieve PC-to-PC file transfers.

I need to write a C++/C# program in windows8 machine to send bit stream from one 
machine to another using the USB to USB Bridge cable.

I can not start, I consulted manufacturers, they do not give me any help. Can any one help me?

I know this is not a good question, but I really need to give a hint by netizens, please heroes keep this question.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Get yourself another cable from a manufacturer who is willing to support you and/or provides an API together with documentation. The costs of those cables should not really break your bank...

Comment: If you know it's a dumb question, don't waste your time asking it and our time closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the above user said, this requires a USB transfer cable which supports API or SDK. I used such a transfer cable and successfully to transfer between the computers in Windows XP.

Please take a look at: [About USB Data Link Cable API](http://www.cnblogs.com/LiuKaiFa/p/USB_data_link_cable_API.html) or [Reference](http://blog.csdn.net/zzkjliu/article/details/12838383), I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Those cables use proprietary software to transfer between the computers, there is no standard interface you can work with.

If the manufactures do not provide any kind of SDK you need to either switch to a different manufacture who does provide a SDK or use a different technology than USB to USB transfer.